# Python int too large to put in SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am getting the error

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER

from the following code block. The file is about 25gb, so it must be read in parts.

```
length = 6128765
# Works on partitions of the dataset
def work(path, fields, partitions, rows, fn):
    import numpy as np
    div = rows // partitions

    parts = np.arange(0, rows, div)
    for i in parts:
        df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='|', names=fields, skiprows=i, nrows=div, encoding='latin-1')
        fn(df)
        del df

def to_sql(df):
    # We can use the pandas.to_sql command to put the data in our SQLlite database:
    df.to_sql("main", sqlite_engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

work("path_to.txt', column_names, 105, length, to_sql)
```

I am using SQLite3 through a sqlalchemy object to interact with it. All columns in the database are TEXT types because I was trying to alleviate this problem.

Anyone have any guidance?

Comment: Just to note: instead of looping and doing your own `skiprows=i, nrows=div`... you can simplify things by using `chunksize=some_size`...

Comment: If you apply that and make sure everything is `dtype=str`, then you might get away with something like: `for df in pd.read_csv(path, sep='|', chunksize=10000, dtype=str): df.to_sql("main", sqlite_engine, if_exists='append', index=False)`...

Comment: @jonclements Thank you, this worked!

Comment: Where in the code block are you getting the error.  (And would your code be more efficient if you only imported numpy once, globally?)

Comment: @RonJohn Yes, good catch. fixed with the change above, your suggestion did help greatly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Problem

I just encountered the same error message. It seems from what is said in this [github issue](https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility/issues/191#issuecomment-77232465) that this is a problem of sqlite3 not handling unsigned 64-bit numbers.

### Overflow Errors

By the way, an *Overflow Error* happens when you get out of the bounds of the number type.

**Example**

If you add 1 to the number 15, which is stored as a  4-bit integer you get 0, because 16 is 10000 in binary, but only the last four bits (0000) can be stored.

[**1111**] + [**0001**] = 1 [**0000**]

### The Solution?

So the only kind of workaround I see, would be to store your integer as a string.